# tableview search segue from other TableViewController

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uisearchbar, segue

So I am trying to implement a TableView Search Bar, which I have set-up and working up to the search bar viewcontroller, but am having trouble segueing to the detail view (i.e. the cell clicked in search results table). I am using this tutorial which starts from a scratch swift file and has the tableView Search as the initial ViewController. So to reiterate, the tableView Search Bar is in between other tableViews, and is not the initial VC (Hopefully I explained that correctly. I have noticed that the "Show" segue is not an option from the search table to the detail ViewController... Here is the code...and also attached screenshot of storyboards

Thanks very much in advance!

[image]

```
//  InitialViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
     var arrayOfPersons: [Person] = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         self.setUpPersons()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setUpPersons()
    {
        var person1 = Person(name: "Anthony Valentine", number: 60, imageName: "Anthony Valentine.png")
        var person2 = Person(name: "Dan Meier", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person3 = Person(name: "Mark Druffel", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person4 = Person(name: "Brittany Donnelly", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person5 = Person(name: "David Moss", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person6 = Person(name: "Ben Matthews", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person7 = Person(name: "Alex Curtis", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person8 = Person(name: "Christine Meier", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")
        var person9 = Person(name: "Billy Kolesar", number: 10, imageName: "Dan Meier.png")


        arrayOfPersons.append(person1)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person2)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person3)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person4)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person5)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person6)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person7)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person8)
        arrayOfPersons.append(person9)

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayOfPersons.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell


        let person = arrayOfPersons[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(person.name, rightLabelInt: person.number, imageName: person.imageName)


        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let person = arrayOfPersons[indexPath.row]

        var detailedViewController: DetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController")! as DetailViewController

        detailedViewController.nameString = person.name
        detailedViewController.ageInt = person.number
        detailedViewController.myDetailedImageName = person.imageName

        self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}



//  Friends.swift
//  TravelAppSwiftPrototype
//
//  Created by Daniel on 10/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dan Meier. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

struct Candy {
    let category : String
    let name : String
}



//
//  SearchFriendsViewController.swift

import UIKit

class SearchFriendsViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var candies = [Candy]()

    var filteredCandies = [Candy]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Sample Data for candyArray
        self.candies = [Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"chocolate Bar"),
            Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"chocolate Chip"),
            Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"dark chocolate"),
            Candy(category:"Hard", name:"lollipop"),
            Candy(category:"Hard", name:"candy cane"),
            Candy(category:"Hard", name:"jaw breaker"),
            Candy(category:"Other", name:"caramel"),
            Candy(category:"Other", name:"sour chew"),
            Candy(category:"Other", name:"gummi bear")]

        // Reload the table
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.filteredCandies.count
        } else {
            return self.candies.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchFriendsCell") as UITableViewCell

        var candy : Candy
        // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            candy = candies[indexPath.row]
        }

        // Configure the cell
        cell.textLabel.text = candy.name
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        self.filteredCandies = self.candies.filter({( candy : Candy) -> Bool in
            var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)
            var stringMatch = candy.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
            return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
        })
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
        let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
        let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: selectedScope)
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!,
        shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
            let scope = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
            self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
            return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FriendsDetail", sender: tableView)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "FriendsDetail" {
            let candyDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
            if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
                let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let destinationTitle = self.filteredCandies[indexPath.row].name
                candyDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
            } else {
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let destinationTitle = self.candies[indexPath.row].name
                candyDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
            }
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Can you post to github?  There are quite a few problems with your classes.  It would be easier to work on a copy of the project.